# I need help understanding this "for" loop

Tags: visual-c++

I understand (I think) what this code is doing, but I would like to know when "i" goes from 0 to 1, as well as when "j" goes from 0 to 1. I think I am most confused with understanding when one increments and how that relates to the other.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
         cout << i * j << endl;
```

This code prints:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
0
4
8
12
16
20
24
28
32
36
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
0
6
12
18
24
30
36
42
48
54
0
7
14
21
28
35
42
49
56
63
0
8
16
24
32
40
48
56
64
72
0
9
18
27
36
45
54
63
72
81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a nested for loop, it is important to note the order in which they increment. Firstly, the inner most loop will increment until it has reached its condition, which would be the "j" loop reaching 10 in your case. Once that loop has finished, it will allow the outer loop, the "i" loop to increment.

To test what i am showing, your could use the print statement `std::cout << i << j << i * j << std::endl;` to test out the code and understand how the increment of the inner and outer loops work.